# PHP / PDO / MSSQL how to get error informations?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I've done a lot of searching, but can't find anything about my issue. I'm using `PDO` with Driver `PDO_DBLIB` to access a MS SQL database. I generally use prepared statements, but if any query fails I don't get any additional information about the error except for this:

`General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [241] (severity 16) [(null)]`

Does anyone have a hint as to how do I retrieve more information about the error (syntax error at...)?

best regards

Michael

Answer (score 17):

To find the error message:

```
-- SQL 2005+
select * from sys.messages where message_id = 241
-- SQL 2000
select * from sysmessages where error = 241
```

It appears that PDO is removing the actual error message text for some reason, but since the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) says that PDO_DBLIB is experimental, this may simply be a bug.

You should also be aware that DBLIB has been [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) by Microsoft since SQL 2005, so you should almost certainly use a different library for connecting to MSSQL.

Comment: AFAIK, MS's driver is for Windows.

Comment: @sims Yes, all Microsoft SQL Server drivers are Windows-only (except the JDBC driver), although since the OP didn't mention his OS or even SQL Server version it's hard to know what the best answer for his scenario is.

Comment: Yes, I just thought I'd make that clear for others who find this page.

Comment: Any way to get the contextual parameters ? Example: `Conversion failed when converting the %1 value %2 to data type %3.`

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Server Error Messages](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-1-500.aspx)

> error 241: Syntax error converting datetime from character string

This format works for me: `date("Ymd H:i:s");`