# Pdo mssql error messages

Tags: sql-server, pdo, freetds

I'm using pdo through freetds driver to connect to Mssql database and I'd like to output detailed sql errors against the generic one.
E.g. I got this generic error from PDO

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 547 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [547] (severity 16) [(null)]
```

But SQL client gives me more details, and I'd like to get them in php. E.g. in the same case:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FKORDINICLIENTI". The conflict occurred in database "dbo.Ordini", column 'IDCliente' of database "dbName".
```

I've already read this old note [PHP / PDO / MSSQL how to get error informations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497534/php-pdo-mssql-how-to-get-error-informations)
and I'd prefer to avoid an additional query.
Thanks.

Comment: please provide your code;  it's very hard to tell what is going on without it

Answer (score -1):

I think code doesn't matter, I know what's wrong in sql, just wanted to access the second code block from php.

I solved using odbc driver instead of freetds.